# For with a struct (Variable update)

Tags: go

Here is an example of a piece of code that I'm trying to use in my program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Code struct {
    Name   string
    Alias  string
    Number int
}

func main() {

    test := Code{
        Name:   "test",
        Alias:  "test",
        Number: 0,
    }
    codes := []Code{test}

    for {
        //Other instructions
        for _, code := range codes {
            code.Number++ // code.Number is incremented but just inside this loop
            test.Number++

            fmt.Println(code.Number)
            fmt.Println(test.Number) // test.Number is incremented
        }
        fmt.Println(test.Number) // test.Number is incremented
        //Other instructions
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

However, every time I come back in my instructions

```
for _, code := range codes
```

the value `code.Number` returns to 0 whereas `test.Number` is well incremented even outside this loop.

I would like to update the value of my struct in the loop and get this new value at each loop turn.

Comment: Please forgive me if I have missunderstood the question but I think you just need to make them references to real objects, like this "codes := []*Code{&test}"

Comment: Please see Gotchas in https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Range

Comment: A variant of https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines.

Comment: That's easy: your slice contains values of type `Code` as its elements. On each iteration, the `code` variable gets assigned _a value_ of the current element: that is, `code` receives a copy of the memory block of the value of the current element. You then modify that copy in `code`, do not copy that value back into the element and so when the value in `code` gets overwritten by the value of the next element on the next iteration, the changes are lost.

Comment: There are two approaches to dealing with the problem: 1) after modification, copy the value in `code` back into `codes[i]`. 2) store pointers to `Code` in the slice, and not `Code` values directly. This will make `code` receive a pointer to a `Code` variable (kept in memory somewhere off the slice), and so both the element and the `code` variable would refer to that same memory block, and all modification done through the pointer in `code` will naturally be "seen" via the (same) pointer kept in the element.

Comment: Note that this might create extra load on GC and perform a bit more poorly when you need to quickly scan the whole slice and process its elements (you won't notice this unless this code lies on a really hot path though).

Answer (score 1):

The instruction `codes := []Code{test}` makes a **copy** of `test` in `codes`. This copy has the value 0 in `Number`.

In the for loop, the range instruction makes another copy of the `codes[0]` struct into `code`. You increment `code.Number`, but `codes[0].Number` is left unmodified. Incrementing `test.Number` does not affect `codes` and `code`.